# The configuration section 'authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

I have tried to use location path tag and authentication tag to let clients access a particular page only if they logged in or just registered:

I have created a separated map called LoggedIn and added a web.config to that map:

> ```
> > <configuration>
> > 
> >   <authentication mode="Forms">
> >     <forms name=".ASPXF2" loginUrl="~/LoggedIn/LoginPage.aspx"
> >         protection="All" path="\" timeout="30" />   </authentication>
> > 
> >   <location path="Default_USER.aspx">
> > 
> >     <system.web>
> > 
> >       <authorization>
> > 
> > 
> >         <deny users="?" />
> >        
> > 
> >       </authorization>
> > 
> >     </system.web>
> > 
> >   </location>
> > 
> > </configuration>
> ```

I have used `<deny users="?" />` to not let access to a page"Default_USER.aspx" those users who have not logged in and got this error: "The configuration section 'authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/#configuration-sample) shows the `<authentication>` node must be under the `<security>` node which must be under the `<system.webServer>` node. Always check the documentation first.

Comment: I have applied what you said now I got this error message: Config Error    Unrecognized attribute 'mode'

Answer (score 0):

> I have applied what you said now I got this error message: Config Error Unrecognized attribute 'mode'

You should put the authentication tag inside the system.web tag.

Like below:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        ... Unrelated configuration settings and comments removed for brevity ...
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

More details about how to use form authentication inside the asp.net, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs).